# In GitHub Actions, how can I uniquely identify the workflow under execution?

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I am using GitHub Enterprise, with a self-hosted runner.  I'm storing build artifacts in dedicated folders so that I can have multiple releases in the same pipeline, without worrying about overwriting old artifacts with new releases.

I'm storing my artifacts using this folder scheme:

```
ARTIFACTS_PATH: "c:/github/artifacts/${{ github.repository_owner }}/${{ github.event.repository.name }}/${{ github.run_id }}"
```

This helps me ensure each workflow run gets its own directory.  But my issue now is I want to implement a "rolling delete", where after each workflow completes it deletes all but the last 5 artifact folders related to that workflow.  But for that I need to be able to map the artifact folders to specific workflows.

So what I'd like to have is something that looks like this, but the workflow_id environment variable doesn't exist.

```
ARTIFACTS_PATH: "c:/github/artifacts/${{ github.repository_owner }}/${{ github.event.repository.name }}/${{ github.workflow_id }}/${{ github.run_number }}"
```

Is there any way I can unique identify the workflow being executed through a unique id or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the workflow file name (unique, as the workflow files have to be stored directly in the folder `.github/workflows`) or the workflow id.

The workflow id can be determined by

- getting the workflow id from a run id via the GitHub Actions REST API. The run id is available via the expression `${{github.run_id}}`.
  source: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs#get-a-workflow-run
- getting the workflow id by specifying the workflow file name as parameter via the GitHub Actions REST API.
  Source: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows#get-a-workflow

  The workflow file name can be parsed from `{{github.workflow_ref}}`

  > The ref path to the workflow. For example, `octocat/hello-world/.github/workflows/my-workflow.yml@refs/heads/my_branch`.

---

If you also have the need to differentiate run attempts, you can use the expression `{{github.run_attempt}}` or `$GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT`.

> A unique number for each attempt of a particular workflow run in a repository. This number begins at 1 for the workflow run's first attempt, and increments with each re-run.

See also:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables

Comment: `${{github.run_id}}` is not enough to represent a unique run, as all the retires of the same run will have the same run_id, instead, we can combine it with `$GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT`

Comment: @XiangZHU I edited my post to include the information about run attempts. Thanks for the hint.